# How to find actual size of a JPEG which is taken from an iOS Image Picker?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, jpeg

Converting data with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and finding number of bytes will not work since compression value is unknown. Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL 

let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetPath as URL], options: nil).lastObject

PHImageManager().requestImageData(for: asset!, options: nil) { (data, value, orientation, info) in
// data?.count will give total bytes 
print(data?.count)
}
```